# update table from a view present in ms sql database

Tags: mysql, sql-server, database, sql-view

I am new to sql database. so kindly forgive me if i dont explain it well. Here it is.

I have a view in my database with following columns and data

```
firstName, lastName, employee_id
Ria, Khanna, 15
Paul, Dcosta, 16
Raven, Sleeaz, 25
```

I want to create a table from this view and add additional columns. Here is how the data should look like.

```
firstName, lastName, employee_id, location, roles
Ria, Khanna, 15,delhi,admin
Paul, Dcosta, 16, new york, developer
Raven, Sleeaz, 25, portland, HR
```

As you can see, it takes the view and updates in the table. I want the firstName, lastName and employee_id to be taken from the view and i will update the location and roles by myself.

**EDIT**

Can you please also highlight how to add view to table without affecting the already created values for location and roles. the answer provided by @rgassvar will always put null values to location and roles. and previously added values would be lost. right?

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? mysql <> sql server.

Comment: Regardless of the DB what you are describing doesn't make sense. A view is just a stored select statement. You are wanting to have a table of values, this does not update automagically or something. Why not just add these two new columns to your view?

Comment: @SeanLange- the view is created since those columns are from a different database. i get the 3 columns from there and put my own columns. this wil create a table i want for my project.

Comment: A view does NOT create a table. It is a view. The best way to deal with this is to add more columns to your view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get everything from the view, then just add two columns as null.

```
SELECT *, null as location, null as roles
INTO new_table
FROM the_view
```

Then just update the location and roles field for each role as you see fit.

EDIT:
After the initial creation you can do:

```
INSERT INTO new_table
SELECT *, null as location, null as roles
FROM the_view
```

or

```
INSERT INTO new_table (firstName, lastName, employee_id)
SELECT *
FROM the_view
```

Comment: Thanks @rgvassar. This will work for first table creation. right ? suppose, i update the table and again want to add the view columns to the table without affecting the location and roles value which i had put in.

Comment: Can you please also highlight how to add view to table without affecting the already created values for location and roles. the above one will keep putting null values to location and roles. and previously added values would be lost. right ?

Comment: The first example will fail if there is already a table. The edit where I added two more examples will only add new rows. The two new fields must be nullable of course and must be added with an `ALTER TABLE` statement if they aren't already present.

Comment: Thanks rgvassar. i will try these. i will vote for the answer once i get 15 points. thank you

Comment: I don't think you need 15 points. Just check the green check mark. Make sure this answer works for you first though.

Comment: Creating a new table decouples you from the source tables.  Any changes then to the table linked to the view would not be reflected in your new tables.  This may be acceptable, but it seems any modifications to the original table would have to be copied on a regular basis.

Comment: Right, I figured that's what he wanted since he wanted to go from view to table. He could have a separate table and then create a second view that has data from both the first view and the table.